# R: Error when converting character column to numeric

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following R dataframe:

```
'data.frame':   902297 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ EVTYPE    : Factor w/ 985 levels "   HIGH SURF ADVISORY",..: 834 834 834 834 834 834 834 834 834 834 ...
 $ FATALITIES: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ INJURIES  : num  15 0 2 2 2 6 1 0 14 0 ...
 $ PROPDMG   : num  25 2.5 25 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 2.5 25 25 ...
 $ PROPDMGEXP: chr  "10^3" "10^3" "10^3" "10^3" ...
 $ CROPDMG   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ CROPDMGEXP: chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
```

The columns `PROPDMGEXP` and `CROPDMGEXP` are characters and I want to convert them to numeric.

The values in the columns are the following:

```
print(unique(newdata$PROPDMGEXP))
> "10^3" "10^6" "0"    "10^9" "1"    "10"   "10^2"

print(unique(newdata$CROPDMGEXP))
> "0"    "10^6" "10^3" "10^9" "10"
```

I have tried to convert the columns to numeric via the following:

```
newdata$PROPDMGEXP <- as.numeric(mydata$PROPDMGEXP)

newdata$CROPDMGEXP <- as.numeric(mydata$CROPDMGEXP)
```

But I get the following error when I do so:

[image]

I am not sure why I am receiving this error and how to resolve it. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert to numeric, R will not attempt to evaluate expressions in the process. Under the hood, `10^3` in R is actually a call to the function `'^'(10, 3)`. If you want powers converted to numbers directly, you can use `e` notation instead. For example:

```r
s <- c("10^3", "10^6", "0", "10^9", "1", "10", "10^2")

as.numeric(s)
#> [1] NA NA  0 NA  1 10 NA
#> Warning message:
#> NAs introduced by coercion    

s2 <- gsub("0\\^", "e", s)
s2
#> [1] "1e3" "1e6" "0"   "1e9" "1"   "10"  "1e2"   

as.numeric(s2)
#> [1] 1e+03 1e+06 0e+00 1e+09 1e+00 1e+01 1e+02
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use an `eval(parse(.))` approach.

```
unname(sapply(c("10^3", "10^6", "0"), function(x) eval(parse(text=x))))
# [1] 1e+03 1e+06 0e+00
```

Your error probably probably comes from mixing `newdata` and `mydata` which have different dimensions.